# Change Image Links From Attachment Page To Image URL

Tags: wordpress

Looking for a SQL query which updates all image links from attachment page to image file in WordPress.

Comment: elaborate your question!

Answer (score 3):

WordPress attachment pages are generated on the fly. For any attachment (an uploaded file) there always exists an attachment page that can be retrieved via http://wordpress.lo/?attachment_id=$ID, where `$ID` is the attachment id in the `wp_posts` database with `post_type` set to `attachment`. It's `guid` field, however is always set to the direct URL that it can be reached via, for example http://wordpress.lo/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/my-upload.png.

However, posts that are published with media attached to them and with permalinks turned on the URLs are always turned into pretty ones, in the form of http://wordpress.lo/2015/01/mypost/attachment-slug for example.

I have to assume that you're up against an issue where all your attachments inside posts and pages are wrapped in anchor links that lead to the attachment page instead of the direct path. This is an issue with the post content and how the image was inserted into the post in the first place and has nothing to do with how the data is structured in the database.

The `wp_posts.post_content` field contains these attachment URLs. Converting these to direct URLs directly can be done but is quite a tricky task since you can't know what sort of attachment URL was generated. A dirty approach would be to parse the content of each post/page looking for images wrapped `<a>` tags and changing their URL. Luckily all attachment links have a `rel` attribute that contains "attachment".

I will not recommend [the Cthulhu way of partsing HTML](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) so using the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) API is the way to go here.

Here's a sketch of code that you can run in `functions.php` of your theme, for example. Do backup your database beforehand, I can't guarantee that this will not blow up in our faces.

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // Get all posts with
        'post_type' => array( 'any' ), // any post type
        's' => 'rel="attachment' // with our target pages
    ) );

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML( $post->post_content ); // Parse the content
        foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'a' ) as $a ) {
            if ( $a->getAttribute( 'rel' ) && strpos( $a->getAttribute( 'rel' ), 'attachment' ) !== false ) {
                // Good candidate, replace rel and href by those in image
                $src = $a->getElementsByTagName( 'img' )->item( 0 )->getAttribute( 'src' ); // get the src
                $a->setAttribute( 'href', $src ); // set the href to the src
                $a->removeAttribute( 'rel' ); // Cleanup rel
            }
        }
        // Strip the extras
        $content = preg_replace( '#<!DOCTYPE.*?>\n#', '', str_replace( array( '<html><body>', '</body></html>' ), '', $dom->saveHTML() ) );

        // Save the post back
        wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post->ID, 'post_content' => $content ) );
    }
} );
```

Some quick test in my local environment showed promising results. Some things to note:

1. This is dirty and may not work with some edge cases, especially where humans had modified the URLs. The code relies on attachment code generated by WordPress 4.1 so be careful, can't know what quirks there might be.
2. Backup your database before running the code and do understand what the code does before running it.
3. If you have a lot of posts the page might timeout, make sure there's enough time for it not to. It is, however, safe to run it multiple times, since we get rid of the "rel" markers and they won't be brought in when running again.
4. Backup the database. Seriously.